# Page cannot be displayed - .net core on IIS8

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to deploy a simple hello world .net core app on iis8.
It runs fine in local dev env. When deployed to iis I get "This page
cannot be displayed".

After deploy, I run dotnet .\TestApp.dll from console and then browse to
http://localhost:5000/. It runs fine. But not on iis.

Application pool set to No managed code.
Error pages is set to Detailed errors.
Web.config seems fine:

There is a log file in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
but there are nothing of interest written there.
And I cant find any logs in the event viewer.

Contents of app_offline.htm does not get served.

Bindings
Type: http
IP-adress: 192.168.1.112
Port: 84
Host name: testapp

On the server I have this installed:

- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.3 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2 - 003156
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.3 & 1.1.0 - Windows Server Hosting
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.1.0 - Runtime

Local dev env:

- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2 - 003131
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling preview 2
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.3 - SDK RC 4
- Microsoft .NET Core 1.1.0 - SDK 1.0.0 Preview 2 - 003177

Do you know how to proceed?